# Twitter Bootstrap scrollable table rows and fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to make a table with a fixed header row and scrollable body rows? I'm using twitter bootstrap if that matters.

This is an example of what I'm trying to create:

http://www.siteexperts.com/tips/html/ts04/page1.asp

All the examples I've seen break it into two separate tables. Was wondering if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Twitter bootstrap also automatically adjusts the column sizes based on content so that's another reason I'd like to keep it in one table

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: The link in your question is now dead.

Comment: the link is not dead when I click it (the link from Yankee at least that I can see)

Answer (score 52):

Just stack two bootstrap tables; one for columns, the other for content. No plugins, just pure bootstrap (and that ain't no bs, haha!)

```
  <table id="tableHeader" class="table" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
  </table>
  <div style="overflow-y:auto;">
    <table id="tableData" class="table table-condensed" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                ...
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

<kbd>[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/Mq52k/16/)</kbd>

The content table div needs `overflow-y:auto`, for vertical scroll bars. Had to use `table-layout:fixed`, otherwise, columns did not line up. Also, had to put the whole thing inside a bootstrap panel to eliminate space between the tables.

Have not tested with custom column widths, but provided you keep the widths consistent between the tables, it should work.

```
    // ADD THIS JS FUNCTION TO MATCH UP COL WIDTHS
    $(function () {

        //copy width of header cells to match width of cells with data
        //so they line up properly
        var tdHeader = document.getElementById("tableHeader").rows[0].cells;
        var tdData = document.getElementById("tableData").rows[0].cells;

        for (var i = 0; i < tdData.length; i++)
            tdHeader[i].style.width = tdData[i].offsetWidth + 'px';

    });
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the column headers does not line up with the column content.

Comment: Probably due to the scroll bar, but close enough for my needs! With some tweaking I'm sure someone can fix it, I'm surprised it's so difficult with such a great framework like bootstrap,

Comment: This is the least ugly solution I've found that doesn't involve wonky JS, so thanks for that. The misalignment is minimal, but it would be nice to find a full fix.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing because I have knockout bound controls in the header. The various fixed header plugins make a dumb copy of the header, and my knockout controls don't function. Now my problem is that I'd need to have some fixed columns too (the first 3 columns), which also contain knockout controls).

Comment: To make the column content line up with the column headers, put the same class for column content as column header. Like `col-sm-3` for `th` and `col-sm-3` for `td` for the corresponding column content

Comment: @abhisek tried [that](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq52k/168/), doesn't seem to make any difference; any ideas why?

Comment: @raffian it doesn't make any difference because the table columns are equally divided (almost). But if the table contents are larger than the header, the table is messed up.

Comment: You can use table-layout:fixed but then just plug in the col-md-1, etc... It would look like <th class="col-md-1"> and  <td class="col-md-1">.

Comment: So many up votes for this answer which  only works like %0.01 of the cases: when it is ok to have equal column width.
Just surprised...

Comment: Does make sense to create two table when in fact i just want one?  Doesnt seems to be fair creating a table with just having a header.. Sorry but for me doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a jQuery plugin that does exactly that:
http://fixedheadertable.com/

Usage:

> `$('selector').fixedHeaderTable({ fixedColumn: 1 });`

Set the `fixedColumn` option if you want any number of columns to be also fixed for horizontal scrolling.

EDIT: This example http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html is much better in my opinion, although with DataTables you'll need to get a better understanding of how it works in general.

EDIT2: For Bootstrap to work with DataTables you need to follow the instructions here: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2 (I have tested this and it works)- For Bootstrap 3 there's a discussion here: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/53462 - (I haven't tested this)

Comment: I was going to suggest DataTables, but this is a much simpler implementation of his requirement.

Comment: You are right actually. I played a bit with this and ended up using DataTables with the "sScrollY": "200px" option.

Comment: For me the fixedHeaderTable solution had the negative side effect of affecting the style of the header.

Comment: Doesn't work with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: For bootstrap to work with DataTables you need to follow the instructions from here: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, I tried doing this by just doing a fixed position row, but this way seems to be a much better one. Source at bottom.

css

```
thead { display:block; background: green; margin:0px; cell-spacing:0px; left:0px; }
tbody { display:block; overflow:auto; height:100px; }
th { height:50px; width:80px; }
td { height:50px; width:80px; background:blue; margin:0px; cell-spacing:0px;}
```

html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>hey</th><th>ho</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
        <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: So the trick is to change the display to block for thead and tbody.  This works nicely, but it unfortunately takes away the browsers auto column width sizing for me.  Is there anyway to get that back?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @ChrisHafey. Is there any solution?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover rsk-tbl vScrollTHead">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Risk Element</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Risk Value</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
<div class="vScrollTable">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover rsk-tbl vScrollTBody">
                <tbody>
                <tr class="">
                    <td>JEWELLERY</td>
                    <td>Jewellery business</td>

                </tr><tr class="">
                    <td>NGO</td>
                    <td>none-governmental organizations</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>





.vScrollTBody{
  height:15px;
}

.vScrollTHead {
  height:15px;
}

.vScrollTable{
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

having two tables for head and body worked for me