# How can I set the proper width for this div?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, width

I'm building a personalized table, and I want to make the scroll with the fixed header possibile. I've created a div which will substitute the original header table and will be fixed.

I made a simple JS function:

```
function resizeCol(numerocolonne){

var leng= $("tbody tr").length;
for(i=1;i<=numerocolonne; i++){
    var bigger=$('[value="1-'+i+'"]').width();
    $('[value="0-'+i+'"]').width(bigger);
}

}
```

which calculate the *width* of the columns and set the width for the fake header. All works good, except that I don't know how to allineate properly the fake header columns and the real ones.

I don't know if I explained myself clearly, so here is a fiddle:

[FIDDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ciaoben/aVT7W/262/)

I can't make the *#header* div wider than the window.

Comment: I think you left out some code. Where is the header you're talking about? And your `resizeCol` function isn't in your fiddle.

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly what you're trying to do with the header vs what it's actually doing?

Comment: i want that the div#header reflect exactly the theader of the table. So, after having done that, i will sostitute the theader with div and make the header fixed while scrolling without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten you started with this:

```
resizeCol(14);


function resizeCol(numerocolonne){
    $('#datatable_pagament_invisibile thead').clone().appendTo('#header');
    var $headers = $('#datatable_pagament_invisibile th');
    $headers.each(function(index, el) {
        $('#header').width($('#datatable_pagament_invisibile').width());
        //$('#header thead th').height($('#datatable_pagament_invisibile thead').height());
        $('#header th').eq($headers.index(this)).width($(this).width());
    });
}
```

It takes a different approach than what you were doing (mainly because the way you were doing it was going to require similar work anyway) -- it clones the thead and puts it in another div which then mimics the width of the table and columns.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aVT7W/263/).

You may also be interested in [another solution that I found posted in another similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821032/485418) I would go with this is if fits your situation/code. I think it's a much simpler and cleaner solution.

Comment: brilliant solution. Many thanks! i would like to ear your opinion about hiding the real thead to fix the cloned one. What would you do?

Comment: You can either hide it or just leave it alone. If you fix it in the right place no one will know the difference between it being hidden or not.

Comment: i'm stucked in the final step... i can't make it work.. could you help me? I used an absolute positioning for cover the real one.. but i can't  make it fixed..

Comment: ty, but i've tried this way, but if you notice, when changing the width of the page, the columns lose their alignement...

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/aVT7W/280/ -- it calls `resizeCol` when the window is resized. EDIT: moved some code around too.

Comment: you 're amazing! ty very much.. i was totally stucked. This solution is great and not too complicate. Brilliant. Now i 've just to work a little on the scrollLeft to make it work with bootstrap grid. Thanks again, i owe you a couple of beers !