# How to make fixed column headers for a bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I am trying to make the columns header of my bootstrap table fixed so that when I scroll the data items of the table, the column headers don't move.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42625/) with example

I've tried the CSS below, however, it doesn't make the headers fixed and further messes up the entire look and feel of the table:

```
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try any of the other dups on this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483378/twitter-bootstrap-scrollable-table-rows-and-fixed-header

Comment: Can you update to the correct fiddle? It looks like this is just the bootstrap 3 template fiddle

Comment: @maxshuty updated: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42625/

Comment: @Anthony this gets you pretty close: https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/DTcHh/42626/ - obviously you will need to play around a bit to get things lining back up again